# Unable to read dynamically created worksheets of excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have to load data from two excel worksheets and process them using C#. The following is my code. This works fine when the worksheets are static. However, when I try to read sheets which are dynamically created from other worksheets within the file, they don't show up in the sheets collection.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string excelConnectionString = connectionString;
        excelConnectionString = excelConnectionString.Replace("*", filePath);
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = excelConnectionString;

        DataTable sheets = GetSchemaTable(excelConnectionString);

        DataSet dsSalaryAndLabor = new DataSet();
        
        //Read both the Salary and Labor Worksheets
        foreach (DataRow row in sheets.Rows)
        {
            //Code to read data and populate dataset
        }
```

Comment: I'll post this as an answer if it's correct, but I'm guessing from the minimal details here that you're not saving the workbook after dynamically creating the sheets. Doesn't OleDb read the file as it is currently saved?

Comment: Do the dynamically created worksheets open in MS Excel if you double click the file? If not, please post C# code of how you are dynamically creating them.

Comment: peterpie, yes if I double click the file it opens in Excel